# Can't get Instagram Carousel children media

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I used "GET [https://graph.instagram.com/{media-id}/children](https://graph.instagram.com/%7Bmedia-id%7D/children)
?access_token={access-token}" API to get list of Carousel children".

When I use "https://graph.instagram.com/{Carousel_children_id}?access_token={access-token}&fields=caption,id,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username, I get an error - "Field is not available for Carousel children media.".

I wonder how can I get  Carousel children details?

Comment: Is that supposed to be the full error message? Does it not say _which_ field it is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Just because I just stumbled across the same issue: For some reason, carousel children don't support the `caption` field. Fun fact: But the `children` field can be used here, which is somewhat illogical.

However, just omit the `caption` field, when requesting child media data, and you are good to go.